# Catch exceptions in spark sql reflect function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark code that decodes url encoded string:

```
df.withColumn("clean_url", F.expr("""reflect("java.net.URLDecoder", "decode", url, "UTF-8")"""))
```

But sometimes it gets string with illegal characters and throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "\x"
```

How can i skip those exceptions and return NULL if string can not be decoded?

I tried pyspark UDF functions to skip exceptions, but on large set of data stumble on OOM errors and performance decline. So prefer using inbuild sql functions. I don't want to rewrite whole code in scala with UDFs to catch that exception. I am hoping to handle it with spark sql functions.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the string first by changing `%` to `%25`.

From my experience, there is no way for us to auto skip the exception in SQL when using reflect UDF to invoke a Java function.